# How to force ActionBar to reevalute bar and overflow menu in multi-window support

Tags: android, android-actionbar, multi-window

I have added support for the Samsung multi-window feature to my android app. All seems to work OK, except when the app is run in multi window mode, the action bar does not adjust the number of buttons to match the reduced app window size. When the window gets smaller, less buttons fit and I'd like these to be moved to the overflow menu, and vice versa when the app window gets bigger again. Because I need backward compatibility with android 2.2 I'm using:

```
android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat
```

with

```
MenuItemCompat.setShowAsAction(item, MenuItemCompat.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);
```

I have set up a globalLayout listener to detect size changes as per Samsung documentation 3-8-9. Handling Layout Changes in http://developer.samsung.com/s-pen-sdk/technical-docs-09

Using this, I see the listener firing with the correct new width / height.
This seems the perfect place to update the actionbar / overflow menu - but how to do that?
I have tried toggling some action bar properties like "ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE" to let the bar rebuild itself, but to no avail.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The way to force a refresh is `supportInvalidateOptionsMenu`. I think the limits are based on resources, so that might still not fix it..

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but calling supportInvalidateOptionsMenu does indeed not fix the problem.

Comment: As I suspected, appcompat controls the number of buttons via resources - `abc_max_action_buttons` in particular. Try doing `getResources().getInteger(R.integer.abc_max_action_buttons)` before and after the resize. I bet you will see the same value. If that's the case, the solution is to update the Configuration but we'll get to that if you can confirm my hunch.

Comment: I see no R.integer.abc_max_action_buttons in android-support-v4.jar, entering that value results in an unknown identifier. Searching for that ident shows references to support-v7 only.

Comment: I created a small test app based on v11 Api minimum - not using the support.v4 library but instead the regular ActionBar. This behaves a little better when resizing the app: action bar buttons are better right aligned and do not become as easily partly invisible/ cut-off, but the invisible buttons are still not moved to the overflow menu when resizing. I also tried (delayed and direct) invalidateOptionsMenu() in a globalLayout Listener but that does not solve it.

Comment: Ah, sorry, for some reason I assumed you were using AppCompat. The field is still called "max_action_buttons" but it's not part of the SDK. Anyway, try updating the Configuration with Configuration.update. In particular, you want to change smallestScreenWidth and screenWidth to be the smaller dimensions that Samsung give you   (make sure to convert to dps where necessary)

Comment: I tried adjusting the Configuration via updateFrom() and setTo() with a smallestWidth and width / 4, and after that calling invalidateOptionsMenu, but unfortunately neither way it works.